# How in coq to use lemma a=b backwards?

Tags: logic, coq, proof

Suppose I have a lemma `L` that says

```
forall x, x + 1 + 1 = x + 2.
```

If my goal is of the form `a + 1 + 1 = b`

I can write a command `rewrite L` to get a goal of the form `a + 2 = b`

However, if my goal is of the form `a + 2 = b`

**how to apply the lemma backwards to get a goal** `a + 1 + 1 = b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say

```
rewrite <- L. (* Rewrite right to left *)
```

For symmetry, there's also `rewrite -> L`, which is the same as `rewrite L` (rewrite left to right).

This is documented in [Coq's tactic reference](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.rewrite:~:text=rewrite%20<-%20term,-Uses%20the%20equality%20term1%20=%20term%202%20from%20right%20to%20left).